# PHP redirection

Tags: php, redirect

[image]

I have 4 php pages as `casting_score.php`, `machining_score.php`, `extrusion_score.php` and `addvendor.php`. First three links are linked with `dropdown` and `addvendorpage` is the default page which should pop up before navigating to other page.

As per my logic when it redirects to casting.php through dropdown it should check first

```
if $_SESSION['somevendorname'] is not empty.
if(empty($_SESSION['vendorname])){ header("location:addvendor.php") }
```

Similarly if session is empty in any page it redirects to landing page (i.e addvendor). Further this how can we go to main page after storing vendor details in session.

Comment: addvendor.php is the landing page. redirection is from castingscore.php extrusion.php, machinging.php

Comment: I want if user redirect manually , he should enter vendor detail before going to the page and that detail will be saved in session for further calculations

Comment: If I go to `addvendor.php`, after filling the details, where would I be redirected if I clicked "Proceed"?

Comment: addvendor is redirecting to castingpage if session['vendorname '] is not empty

Comment: How can I enter the remaining two page if `addvendor.php` will redirect me to `casting_page.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is needed to go through `addvendor.php`, you can use `$_POST` instead for checking, like this:

**addvendor.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="casting_score.php">
    <input type="text" name="vendorName" required/>
    <input type="text" name="vendorEmail" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="vendorSubmit" />
</form>
```

**casting_score.php**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['vendorSubmit'])){
        header('Location:addvendor.php');
        exit;
    }
    ...rest of code
?>
```

This will make sure that if the user didn't filled the form and clicked the button, they will be redirected back to `addvendor.php`

Or if you want to use sessions, you can use this:

**addvendor.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['vendorSubmit'])){
        $_SESSION['vendorName'] = $_POST['vendorName'];
        $_SESSION['vendorEmail'] = $_POST['vendorEmail'];
        header('Location: casting_score.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="vendorName" required/>
    <input type="text" name="vendorEmail" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="vendorSubmit" />
</form>
```

**casting_score.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['vendorName']) && isset($_SESSION['vendorEmail'])){
    $vendorName = $_SESSION['vendorName'];
    unset($_SESSION['vendorName']);
    unset($_SESSION['vendorEmail']);
    ...rest of codes
} else {
    header('Location:addvendor.php');
    exit;
}
...rest of codes
?>
```

Using [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) is important so that the previouse data will be removed and cannot be reused to redirect to `casting_score.php` without going through `addvendor.php`

***NOTE***: This answer is based on what I understood, so for any clarifications, just comment and I will change this answer accordingly

Comment: Can you join a session and see the whole project?

Comment: Nevermind i figured out a way. Save the current url in session and then use heared to redirect to the that page later with session only.